# how to capture output from rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser" on a bash shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell

I want to capture the output on the bash shell when running the following command at the bash prompt.

```
rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser"
```

Basically `checkuser()` returns a value of either 1 or 0, which I want to capture at the shell that launched the "rails runner" command.

Based on the written value at the shell, I would like to execute some other command. This `checkuser()` connects to the cloud, accesses the SQL server and returns the value, so I need to load the rails env.

I run this command in hudson "execute shell" window. How do I go about achieving this task?
Does rake help me with this?

Edit:

```
#to keep things simple:
module MyCloud
  class Deployment
    def self.checkuser
      return 20
    end
  end
end 

I am running the command from ubuntu box:
sreeni@ubuntu:~/work/co/RoR$ res="$(rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser")"
sreeni@ubuntu:~/work/co/RoR$ echo $res

sreeni@ubuntu:~/work/co/RoR$
```

I want to capture the value that is returned from that check_user() to a variable on the bash shell.

Comment: did you try to save it anyhow?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Are you talking about a value `0` or `1` that's returned or an exit code? Doesn't hudson automatically abort a run if an "execute shell" step doesn't return 0?

Comment: checkUser() returns either 1 or 0 depending upon whether user exists or not; I am not referring to the exit status. I launch the rails runner command from a bash command prompt and I like to capture its output at the bash shell.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: You are confusing **return values** (objects returned to the *same-language* caller) with **text output**. You need to `puts 20` to capture it as a string. You cannot capture return values from one language in another language without a [foreign function interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) or similar mechanism. A rare exception is the interface between *nix shells like Bash and Dash, where you can capture the return value from one in the other because they both implement something similar to a [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html).

To get the *exit code*, test the command or `$?`:

```
rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Short form:

```
if rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser"
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

To get *string* output, use a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (and yes, [those inner quotes are correct](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Examples)):

```
result="$(rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser")"
if [ "$result" = '0' ]
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

Short form:

```
if [ "$(rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser")" = '0' ]
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Failure"
fi
```

To capture both output and exit code:

```
result="$(rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser")"
exit_code=$?
```

Comment: @I0b0: checkuser() returns a value which I want to capture it but not the exit status. Let's say it return 20 and I want to capture it.

Comment: Please clarify what you want. The answer clearly covers both the exit code and output. There is no such thing as a "return value" other than the exit code in shell code.

Comment: this is not a valid command
result="$(rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser")"

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result? I do believe that does exactly what it says on the label.

Comment: I tried the command before but earlier one of the quotes was missing but still it doesn't return the value I am after. Below, I tried to display the value of the $result but it returned nothing.


sreeni@ubuntu:~/work/co/RoR$ result="$(rails runner "MyCloud::Deployment.checkuser")"
sreeni@ubuntu:~/work/co/RoR$ echo $result

sreeni@ubuntu:~/work/co/RoR$

Comment: If the command prints nothing on standard output, then that's what you'll get.

Comment: I added more info to keeps things simple; see above; my function returns 20 which I want to capture in a shell variable.

Comment: I had to modify the check_user() i.e. instead of "return 20", I changed to "puts 20", then I was able to capture. thanks I0b0 for your help.